# Parsing Json document. Can you explain why key giving values? Also help parse my list better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am teaching myself jquery and json for work. I have been making great progress, but now got myself very confused. My ultimate goal is to be able to parse json from a text file I have and then store them as javascript objects so I can do more stuff with it.

This is what I have done. I have the following data in json format (created from a java class I wrote). Please note that data.json looks like this:

```
{"Time": 15, 
"Distance": 20, 
"Position":[{"x":5,"y":10},
{"x":15,"y":20}]}
```

I formatted the above in this question to be easier to read by being on separate lines, but the raw file contains it all on one line.

I used the following code in a script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("ready!");
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(key,val)
    {
        alert(val.Time);
        alert(val.Distance);
            alert(val.Position);
    });
});
```

But what it outputs is three "undefined" alerts. Why? My ultimate goal is to store Time, Distance, and the Position as javascript objects so I can draw them on a graph I made in html. However, I am obviously no way close to that because my alerts are not reading/parsing json objects right.

So I changed it to as follows, on a hunch:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("ready!");
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(key,val)
        {
            alert(key.Time);
            alert(key.Distance);
                alert(key.Position);
        });
    });
```

Well, these is mostly promising in that I get the following alerts:

```
Alert 1 Output: 15, 
Alert 2 Output: 20, 
Alert 3 Output: [Object Object], [Object Object]
```

Okay, I am closer, but now *very* confused. Shouldn't the key be giving me alert output "Time", "Distance", and "Position" and val be "15", "20", and "[Object Object], [Object Object]". I thought json kind of works like a hashtable. Hmmmm.

Also, do I need to do a .each(key, val) to parse my list called Position? Because obviously Object Object is not going to help me much. I basically want to save this list Position as a javascript obj like

```
myList = [[5, 10], [15,20]]
```

Anyway, that is my thinking. I thank you for your time. I will upvote anyone who replies and helps me out. This is important to me.

Regards, 
GeekyOmega

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for `getJSON`.  In particular, look at the signature of the callback function.  It is not `key, value`.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Your second version shouldn't work, either. `travelTime` != `Time`, `travelDistance` != `Distance`, and there's nothing named `route`.

Comment: Yes, that was terrible of me. I edited it to reflect my code change. I hated the variable names and made them more simple in json and here. Good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your `function(key,val) { ... }`, but this isn't how jQuery's getJSON works at all.  The callback function for getJSON takes three parameters, `data`, `textStatus` and `jqXHR`.  I suspect you will find that the `data` parameter is essentially the javascript object you wanted to build, except with fields 'x' and 'y' rather than each nested array.  To get the data out, I'd do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Position.length; i ++)
   do_something_with (data.Position[i].x, data.Position[i].y);
```

Comment: I was trying to create alerts to read the data. If that works, then I would do something like, val time = key.Time; Hope that elaborates what I was going at. Trying to play with this as I read the documentation to understand. But then got super confused.

Answer (score 2):

`key` and `val` as you have them are misnamed. The first parameter to the `$.getJSON()` callback is the JSON object. See [the API Doc example](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) where the callback function is just passed a parameter called `data`.

`[Object Object]` is the default `toString()` for objects in javascript. To get the values of your object array, you can iterate `data.Position` and access the `x` and `y` properties of each object in the array.

**Edit** to respond to your comment:

You could always change the Position property in your JSON to be generated as an array of arrays instead of an array of objects.

Or, on the client side, you could do something like this:

```
var points = [];
$.each(data.Position, function(item) {
    points.push([item.x, item.y]);
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can save my data.Position in a javascript array object? Something that will give me something like myList = [[5,10], [15,20]]. I'm really, really, really close now.

Comment: @GeekyOmega Edited answer to respond.

Answer (score 1):

Re-read your key names.  Words like `route` and `travelTime` appear in your code but not in your JSON.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("ready!");
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(key)
        {
            console.log(key.Time);
            console.log(key.Distance);
            console.log(key.Position[0]);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I apologize. I changed the json to have better naming convention, then left the legacy code in because my mind is fried today at work. I feel terrible about that and fixed it immediately.

Comment: @GeekyOmega -- so is your problem solved, or do you not understand why it is doing what it is doing?

Comment: This problem is solved, I ran into another one, but I am working on solving that myself (the array I populate using the code above becomes null later on in a initialize function).

Answer (score 0):

when you create a class user javascript,you can write `var pepole={name:"smith",code:"YQ001",println:function(code,name){document.write(this.name+":"+this.code+"<br/>")}};`,json is a class for javascript,but there is no method it's only attribute